# How to clear Fragment from Activity after coming back from another application?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

What is the best way to clear an fragment from Activity after returning back from external intent (ex. email/watsapp etc.) 
I have an fragment which I want to clear(clear from backstack) after coming back from an implicit intent call (ex. ACTION_SEND). I want to clear the fragment but I don't want to close the activity. 
I already tried 'getActivity().onBackPressed()' - in this case my Activity appears before 'email/sms' intent getting called.
I want to clear this fragment after coming back from external intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code in onActivityResult:

```
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG_FRAGMENT);
if(fragment != null) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it. I set a flag whenever I trigger an intent to external app

```
private static final int REQUEST_INTENT_SENT = 1000;
private boolean intentSent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    findViewById(R.id.send_intent).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            startActivityForResult(sendIntent, REQUEST_INTENT_SENT);
            intentSent = true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if(intentSent){
        intentSent = false;
        //Clear your fragment here
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_INTENT_SENT && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED){
        intentSent = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

Answer (score -1):

try if your are getting any callbacks in onactivityresult method as you are using startactivityforresult for send action.